# echo specific words from a variable containing text

Tags: shell

I'm trying to use the echo command to print some specific words from a variable( that has a text in it ) as following :

```
for i in $variable
do
IFS="|"    # the text is in format : word1|word2|word3
first=( "$i" )
echo ${first[1]}
IFS=$OlIFS     # I have a OlIFS variable which I set in the beginning of the code as following : OlIFS=$IFS
done
```

The result is a ton of empty lines. I guess the problem is in the echo command but I'm not too sure
The $variable contains a text in the format of :

```
word1line1|word2line1|word3line1
word1line2|word2line2|word3line2
```

Expected Output is :

```
word1line1
word1line2
.
.
etc
```

If I use ${first[2]}, I want to have word2 as result instead of word1

Comment: What are the contents of your `$variable`?

Comment: a lot of lines in the form of : word1|word2|word3|word4 etc..

Comment: and what is your expected output?

Comment: ecpected output : word1    (line 1)
                            word1    (line 2)
                            etc
(depending on the ${first[1]}, if I have ${first[2} I want to have word 2 as output)

Comment: please [edit] your post with these informations instead of adding them in comments. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're quoting the variable in the array assignment. In this case, you do want to leave it unquoted to get the word splitting effect.

Quoted:

```
$ variable="word1line1|word2line1|word3line1
word1line2|word2line2|word3line2"

$ for word in $variable; do ( IFS='|'; words=("$word"); echo "${words[0]}" ); done
# ............................................^.....^
word1line1|word2line1|word3line1
word1line2|word2line2|word3line2
```

Unquoted:

```
$ for word in $variable; do ( IFS='|'; words=($word); echo "${words[0]}" ); done
# ............................................^....^
word1line1
word1line2
```

I'm using a subshell to localize the IFS assignment